# How to change Xamarin Forms Frame Border Thickness

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin Forms (VS for Mac) to create an Android App and I'm using the frame control to give certain areas of the UI background and border. However I'm stuck at trying to change the border thickness. I am currently using the suggested approach of a frame nested in a frame but this does not seem to be a very elegant solution, it all means when the corners are rounded that the inner radius has to be set to a slightly smaller radius to the outer in order that it looks correct. Is there another solution here?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Show the relevant code and explain what you've tried and what didn't work.

Comment: In .NET MAUI, you could use a [Border](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border) control as an alternative